# Locking multiple access to same page/view

Tags: jsf-2

Environment: CDI 2.0, JSF 2.x with Primefaces 7 or 8.

I want to have a page/view, where I can edit some data and stored in filesystem.
But I want prevent to access the same view from multiple users (session) twice.
So a "second" user will be informed, somebody is also using the same section.

Question: How can I implement a locking (mutex)? I can't find any hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you detect that a user actually "left" a section? A user can navigate or simply close the browser. Due to the nature of how browsers and web applications work I'd say the only viable option if you want to do something like this is to use a web socket to protect that section. With OmniFaces or newer versions of JSF there is a handy component you can use for this purpose. You could also utilize polling with a timeout to get the same end-result.

Comment: Probably back the page with an `@ApplicationScoped` bean and use that to control access to the singleton?